# What tools are necessary to create a juju charm?

Tags: juju, charms

What methods and tools supplied by Ubuntu are necessary to create a juju charm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Charm Tools PPA](https://launchpad.net/~juju/+archive/pkgs) includes the `charms-tools` package, which is useful for creating and testing charms.

`charm create <ubuntu-package-name>` will create a basic charm with filled metadata for you. Use this if you want to build a charm out of something that is already packaged in Ubuntu.

`charm create whatever` will just create a blank charm for you to edit if you want to create a charm for something else, for example one that pulls from the latest upstream source or for something that is not available as a package in Ubuntu.

And lastly you'll want `charm proof` to test to see if your charm is correct.